# How do I categorize outputs in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Let's say I have this MySQL table

```
DATE       | NAME
2011-10-11 | Rock
2011-10-31 | Pen
2011-10-28 | Paper
2010-10-3  | Scissor
2010-3 -2  | Pen
2011-11-1  | Tree
2011-11-2  | Bug
```

When I take them out from the database I want to arrange them in their Date categories...

Im trying to get this output.

```
October 2010

2010-10-3 Scissor

October2011

2011-10-11 Rock
2011-10-31 Pen
2011-10-28 Paper

November 2011

2011-11-1  | Tree
2011-11-2  | Bug
```

The dates in the database is continuously adding, so I cant manually get there dates and values in each separate queries.

Answer (score 3):

1. Put an `ORDER BY date DESC` clause in your SQL query to order the results by the date column.
2. Either loop through the results and output a category title every time the category changes (In your case, the year / month changes), or store the results in a meaningful multidimensional array if you want to reuse the data later (with arguable efficiency), maybe something like:

   ```
   $results = array();
   while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array(...))
   {
       list( $year, $month, $day) = explode( '-', $row['date']);
       $results[ $year ][ $month ][] = $row;
   }

   foreach( $results as $year => $month_array)
   {
       foreach( $month_array as $month => $row_array)
       {
           echo "Category $month $year";
           foreach( $row_array as $row)
           {
               echo $row['date'];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**EDIT** Just as an addition, you may want to look into MySQL's date / time functions, specifically [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), which would allow you to output more human-readible / user-friendly dates using only the database. Of course, you can implement your own methods to convert 01 => January and so forth.

Comment: The Markdown processor is a bit wonky when a code block is part of a list, you need extra indentation to make it behave itself.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the long reply. I tried your code but if I have more than 2 transactions in a single month, it displays 'Category $month $year' twice with each transaction separated by it.

Comment: It shouldn't - Double check that you're forming the `$results` array correctly. Here is a minimal example using some hardcoded rows and adding line breaks - http://codepad.org/RVepZqD7

Comment: I saw what was making display incorrectly. Is there a difference between mysqli_fetch_array() and mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: So one does really need to look for the date to change in PHP? There is no more general solution to this, since I suppose this is a really common task.